# Managing user session length in EE 2.8 +?

Tags: sessions, 2.8

Recently upgraded to EE 2.8.1 and was worried about some things discussed in [this thread](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19971).

Prior to EE 2.8 we were able to use the `user_session_ttl` config to set the user's session to whatever duration we pleased. But that [config](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/general/hidden_configuration_variables.html#user-session-ttl) no longer exists, instead the user's session is now hardcoded to 2 hours (different if remember me is checked) (and cp sessions are 1 hour by default).

Are there any options out there asides from editing core for managing session lengths?

Or perhaps I am missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up reverting the method `_setup_session_length` in Session.php to what it was before EE 2.8 so I can keep using the config variables -- though I still get the new javascript prompt on the CP end.

For convenience sake I'll leave the code here (if this is a problem, please by all means edit/let me know). The `*_session_ttl` config variables are in seconds, you would throw those in your config.php or bootstrap e.g. as `$config['user_session_ttl'] = 9001;`.

```
protected function _setup_session_length()
{
    $u_item = ee()->config->item('user_session_ttl');
    $cp_item = ee()->config->item('cp_session_ttl');

    $this->cpan_session_len = ($cp_item !== FALSE) ? $cp_item : $this->cpan_session_len;
    $this->user_session_len = ($u_item !== FALSE) ? $u_item : $this->user_session_len;

    return (REQ == 'CP') ? $this->cpan_session_len : $this->user_session_len;
}
```